# How to get running application names and match them with the name recorded in a database on android?

Tags: java, android, database, antivirus

I'm trying to build antivirus application. i have a problem when trying to match the running applications package names with the names that recorded in the database using a runtime service.

this is my service:

```
import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.database.*;
import android.os.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.util.*;

public class RuntimeSecurityService extends Service
{
String packagePublicName;

DatabaseManager db;

ActivityManager activityManager;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    db = new DatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());

    CheckRunningApps cra = new CheckRunningApps();
    new Thread(cra).start();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent p1)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    return null;
}

class CheckRunningApps implements Runnable
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        Looper.prepare();

        activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String packName = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();

        Cursor dataBase = db.getAllData();

        while(dataBase.moveToNext())
        {
            packagePublicName = dataBase.getString(1);

            if(dataBase.getString(1).equals(packName))
            {

            }
        }

        final List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo runingServiceInfo : services)
        {
            if (runingServiceInfo.service.getPackageName().equals(packagePublicName))
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and this DatabaseManager.Java:

```
import android.database.sqlite.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.database.*;

public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Virus.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Viruses";

public DatabaseManager(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int p2, int p3)
{

}
public boolean insertData(String name)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("Name", name);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

    if(result==-1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
public Cursor getAllData()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}

}
```

The problem here is runnable class in Runtime service just run for one time.
I need a code that run that process without even stopping for one second.
Putting that process in while(true) make the app using too much memory and decrease the device performance.

Thanks.